# Output Extent (Environment Setting)

Tags: python, arcmap

I would like to know how to set up the Output extent on ArcMAP using Python.

I have a loop to Create Thiessen Polygons, but I didn't mange to change my output extent the size I want.

```
arcpy.Extent(293490,5898230,316430,5930230)

for i in range(3,51,1):
    arcpy.CreateThiessenPolygons_analysis("AVF%i" % i,"AVF%iVoronoi" % i,"ONLY_FID")
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: This should probably be moved to [GIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Cross-posted as http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19239/how-to-set-the-output-extent-environment-setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map extent can be set through the DataFrame object.  See this [ESRI help page](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/DataFrame/00s300000003000000/)
This appears to set the current extent of the data frame.  I don't know if you can set the full or maximum extent of the frame.

```
#arcpy.Extent(293490,5898230,316430,5930230)

#use 'CURRENT' if running from arcmap, when published use MXD on disk
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
newExtent = df.extent
newExtent.XMin, newExtent.YMin = 293490,5898230
newExtent.XMax, newExtent.YMax = 316430,5930230
df.extent = newExtent
```

Comment: oh ok, it is completely different from arcpy.Extent though. Do you know the role of arcpy.Extent?

Comment: arcpy.Extent is the Python class representing a generic extent object. df.extent is and instance of arcpy.Extent, `isinstance(df.extent,arcpy.Extent)` will return True in the example above.